# I am starting to learn python and following a tutorial. Even though I am using the EXACT code of the tutorial, the code isnt working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\driver\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver-win32"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

but it shows the error

> "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\experiment frfr.venv\Scripts\python.exe"
> "C:    \Users\pc\PycharmProjects\experiment frfr\main.py"    File
> "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\experiment frfr\main.py", line 3
> PATH = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\driver\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver-win32"
> ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode
> bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss anything from tutorial, e.g. PATH = **r**"..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `\` in order to do so replace

```
PATH = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\driver\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver-win32"
```

using

```
PATH = "C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\driver\\chromedriver-win32\\chromedriver-win32"
```

`\\` is using to indicate that you mean literal `\`